# taking input from user

Tags: c

```
 i tried to take input from user 
 input type is not determined(can be char or int)
 i wanna take input and store in pointer array
 while i doing that job forr each pointer i wanna take place from leap area
 that is using malloc
  but below code doesnot work why??? 

 int main(void)
{
    char *tutar[100][20],temp;
    int i;
    int n;
    i=0;

    while(temp!='x')
    {
        scanf("%c",&temp);
        tutar[i]=malloc(sizeof(int));
        tutar[i]=temp;
        ++i;
    }

    n =i;
    for(i=0;i<=n;++i)
    {
        printf(" %c  ",*tutar[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

   /*for(i=0;i<=n;++i)
   {
        printf("%d",atoi(*tutar[i]));
   }
    */
}
```

note that;
this cite has problem when rewrite(edit) the previous mail
it is general problem or not

Comment: Sorry mate, but that code's a mess. You're defining a two dimensional array of char pointers, allocating memory to them and then overwriting the pointers to all point to that "temp" variable, leaking all your allocated memory. Neither your question or the code make much sense. I don't think code like this would even compile correctly, let alone run. Please rework the code (preferably from scratch) and if it still doesn't work ask us again, providing more information to go on than just "doesn't work".

Comment: @gcc - Do you write all your questions as riddles?

Comment: @burnt_hand I think he writes all his questions through an automated translator. I can't think of any other way that he'd end up with things like "the previous mail" and "leap area".

Comment: Also, you aren't initializing `temp`, which means it has a distinct chance of starting with the value 'x' (there's only 256 possible values, and one is 'x').  Nor are you accounting for the possibility that somebody might type over 100 characters with no 'x'.

Comment: @Tyler:  I'd bet serious money gcc isn't a native English speaker.  Nothing wrong with that, and I'd say there's enough information here for a good answer.

Comment: @David Not saying there's anything wrong with not being a native English speaker. I just find some things in his posts that suggest he might be using machine translation, so I was pointing out that he probably isn't asking his questions intentionally as "riddles", but rather that we're seeing his questions through the lens of babelfish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems in your code, including:

- you declare `tutar` as a two-dimensional array of pointers to character, then use it as a one-dimensional array
- `tutar[i]=temp` assigns the value of temp (a char) to tutar[i] (a pointer to char), effectively overwriting the pointer to the newly reserved memory block
- you don't initialize `temp`, so it will have garbage value - occasionally it may have the value `x`, in which your loop will not execute

Here is an improved version (it is not tested, and I don't claim it to be perfect):

```
int main(void)
{
    char *tutar[100], temp = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int n;

    while(temp!='x')
    {
        scanf("%c",&temp);
        tutar[i]=malloc(sizeof(char));
        *tutar[i]=temp;
        ++i;
    }

    n =i;
    for(i=0;i<=n;++i)
    {
        printf(" %c  ",*tutar[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Note that unless you really need to allocate memory dynamically, you would be better off using a simple array of chars:

```
    char tutar[100], ...
    ...

    while(temp!='x')
    {
        scanf("%c",&temp);
        tutar[i++]=temp;
    }
    ...
```

For the sake of brevity, I incremented `i` within the assignment statement.