# Update dictionary in python, how do I get input from user?

Tags: python

I want to replace value of key (i.e `db_host`, `addons_path`) with `$$$$`. Both key and value should be provided by user.

My function should ask for 2 questions:

1. which key you want to update?
2. Which value you want to update?

If the user says `key = db_host` and `value = $$$$$`, than it should update that value in the text file.

Input text file contains the following:

```
#Test.txt#
addons_path=/bin/root

admin_passwd = abctest

auto_reload = False

csv_internal_sep = ,

db_host = 90.0.0.1
```

Updated text file:

```
#Test.txt#
admin_passwd = abctest

auto_reload = False

csv_internal_sep = ,

db_host = $$$$$
```

I want to replace the value of a particular key and write it in a file, than replace the old file with new file.

The following function gives me correct output of replacing value in files. How I can change it with user input ?

```
def replace_in_file(filename, key, new_value):
    f = open('/Files/test2', "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.split('=')[0].strip(' \n') == key:
            lines[i] = key + ' = ' + new_value + '\n'
    f = open('Files/test2', "w")
    f.write("".join(lines))
    f.close()

replace_in_file("file.txt", 'db_host', "22222")
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for `input` (Py3) or `raw_input` (Py2).

Comment: why you are not using pickle or shelve module instead *.txt files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [taking input from user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789924/taking-input-from-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you just need this:

```
key = raw_input("which key you want to update? : ")
value = raw_input("Which value you want to update? : ")
```

The program will wait for user input in each case.
Then the 'key' and 'value' variables will contain the values given by the user...

Answer (score 0):

this might work !

```
def replace_in_file(filename, key, new_value):
    f = open('/home/tactix4/Pictures/Ami/Files/tactix4_replace_key/test2', "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.split('=')[0].strip(' \n') == key:
           lines[i] = key + ' = ' + new_value + '\n'
    f = open('/home/tactix4/Pictures/Ami/Files/tactix4_replace_key/test2', "w")
    f.write("".join(lines))
    f.close()

replace_in_file("test2", key, value)

key = raw_input("which key you want to update? : ")
value = raw_input("Which value you want to update? : ")
```